# Unable to install new software due to dartvm?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, software-center, update-manager, software-uninstall

I recently tried running this command to install the dart vm:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
# Get the Google Linux package signing key.
$ sudo sh -c 'curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -'
# Set up the location of the stable repository.
$ sudo sh -c 'curl https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list'
$ sudo apt-get update
```

But this doesn't install the IDE or Dartium so then I ran this:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hachre/dart
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install darteditor
```

But now I'm getting this error when I try to use the terminal to install anything:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
dartsdk : Depends: dartvm (>= 0.5.0.1+r21823-3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I've tried running this to fix it:

```
sudo apt-get -f remove 
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean 
sudo apt-get remove dartvm
sudo apt-get remove darteditor
sudo apt-get remove dartsdk
```

I can't install ppa-purge and I can't remove the previous packages without getting the same error. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it doing this:

```
sudo dpkg --purge dartsdk
sudo apt-get update
```

Everything worked after this.